# How to find a route given a set of noisy points

Tags: pgrouting, routing, noise

First of all, I'm a total noob to GIS problems.
Let's say I have a set of noisy GPS points (tracked while driving) along a number of streets. Is there a way to get the most likely route that generated those points (maybe using pgrouting)? In particular, sometimes, due to noise, a point lies on a crossing street and I don't want the resulting route to contain that street.

Comment: do you have access to ArcMap Network Analyst?

Comment: No. We can only use Open Source tools/APIs. I was hoping there would be an extension to Post GIS.

Comment: this is called map matching. have a look at my blog post: http://karussell.wordpress.com/2014/07/28/digitalizing-gpx-points-or-how-to-track-vehicles-with-graphhopper/

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't see that it was as simple as wheighting the graph according to the distance of the points near the edges and runnging a dijkstra on it. With that it is actually possible to use PostGIS, since pgRouting allows to provide an arbitrary wheighted graph. I'll add an answer by myself to point that out.

Comment: I've now also implemented this idea in a rough prototype: https://github.com/karussell/map-matching

Answer (score 1):

According to Karussells comment, one can define a weighting of the street map graph dependent on the distances of the points to the nearest edges (streets) and then simply run a Dijkstra on that weighted graph. Since pgRouting (an extension of PostGIS for routing) allows to run Dijkstra on an arbitrary weighted graph, the only thing one needs to do is define that graph (i.e. compute the edgje weigts) and run pg_dijkstra (http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/shortest_path.html)

Answer (score 0):

pgRouting does not provide such a functionality. 
There is a semi-automated tool to align GPS points with OSM data named "Slide": http://labs.strava.com/slide/

It's released under open source license and the algorithm could be also implemented as pgRouting function (either as contribution or with funding).